# Creation of object using abstraction fails, likely a simple fix I cannot see

Tags: java, object, constructor, abstraction

A novice question about abstraction and constructors. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I have an abstract class Piece, this is the constructor:

```
public abstract class Piece {

    private int[] location = new int[2];
    private final char color;

    public Piece(char color, int[] location) {
        this.location = location;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

I have a class which extends Piece:

```
public class Bishop extends Piece{

    public Bishop(char color, int[] location) {
        super(color, location);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to test it. However, the following code gives the errors illegal start of expression, illegal start of type, missing ';'

```
public class testing {
    Piece blackBishop = new Bishop('b', {0,0});
}
```

All these files are in the same package. After searching for a solution for hours I have decided to ask for help. Please let me know what I have done incorrectly.

Comment: `Piece blackBishop = new Bishop('b', new int[] {0,0});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{0,0}` can only be used by itself when you declare an int array variable (`int[] var = {0,0};`).

Change

```
Piece blackBishop = new Bishop('b', {0,0});
```

to

```
Piece blackBishop = new Bishop('b', new int[] {0,0});
```

Comment: A simple fix indeed. Thank you so much!